In flutter ,I'm stuck to cancel the snoozing notification in flutter
is there anyone who can help me,I'm stuck since two days to solve a problem in my flutter notification app ,I added a repeat interval and it's displaying notification on its scheduled time and then after in every repeated time for ex. if i select snoozing option in every five minutes so it's displaying in every five minutes very smoothly but I'm unable to cancel notifications snoozing like in alarm we select snoozing option but we have option to cancel it like 'Stop Snoozing' or 'Stop' same I want to add a button in my notification body to cancel notification of that reminder,
please suggest a solution.
I did try my best to solve it,like cancelNotifcation method,a button in my screen to call it to cancel notification.
I'm expecting a button in notification body 'Done' named or any who suits this and when user click n that it prevent any further notification of that specific reminder just this only.This is my notification service code file where I handled to show notifications >>>
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class LocalNotifications {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static final Map<int, bool> _activeNotifications = {};

  static Future<void> init() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse details) {
        handleNotificationResponse(details);
      },
    );
  }

  static Future<void> showNotification({
    required int id,
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String payload,
    required String repeatOption,
  }) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'reminders_channel',
      'Reminders',
      channelDescription: 'Notifications for reminders',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
        AndroidNotificationAction('done', 'Done'),
      ],
    );

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      notificationDetails,
      payload: payload,
    );

    _activeNotifications[id] = true;

    // Schedule the next notification based on repeat option
    _scheduleNextNotification(id, title, body, payload, repeatOption);
  }

  static void _scheduleNextNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, String payload, String repeatOption) {
    Duration? repeatInterval = _getRepeatInterval(repeatOption);
    if (repeatInterval != null && _activeNotifications[id] == true) {
      Future.delayed(repeatInterval, () {
        if (_activeNotifications[id] == true) {
          showNotification(
            id: id,
            title: title,
            body: body,
            payload: payload,
            repeatOption: repeatOption,
          );
        }
      });
    }
  }

  static Duration? _getRepeatInterval(String repeatOption) {
    switch (repeatOption) {
      case 'Every 5 seconds':
        return Duration(seconds: 5);
      case 'Every 5 minutes':
        return Duration(minutes: 5);
      case 'Every 10 minutes':
        return Duration(minutes: 10);
      case 'Every 30 minutes':
        return Duration(minutes: 30);
      case 'Every day':
        return Duration(days: 1);
      case 'Every week':
        return Duration(days: 7);
      case 'Every month':
        return Duration(days: 30); // Approximate
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  static void handleNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse details) {
    if (details.payload != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> reminderDetails =
          extractReminderDetails(details.payload!);
      int id = reminderDetails['id'] as int;
      if (AndroidNotificationAction == 'done') {
        // if (details.actionId == 'done') {
        cancelNotification(id);
        _activeNotifications[id] = false;

        print("Reminder marked as done: ${reminderDetails['title']}");
      } else {
        // Handle tapping the notification
        print("Notification tapped: ${details.payload}");
      }
    }
  }

  static Map<String, dynamic> extractReminderDetails(String payload) {
    return json.decode(payload);
  }

  static Future<void> cancelNotification(int id) async {
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id);
    _activeNotifications[id] = false;
    print("Notification with ID $id has been cancelled");
  }
}`
>>>
and this is create reminder page where i added information of reminder including repeat option>>>`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class CreateReminderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onReminderSaved;

  CreateReminderPage({required this.onReminderSaved});

  @override
  _CreateReminderPageState createState() => _CreateReminderPageState();
}

class _CreateReminderPageState extends State<CreateReminderPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  final _dateController = TextEditingController();
  final _timeController = TextEditingController();

  DateTime? _selectedDate;
  TimeOfDay? _selectedTime;
  String? _selectedRepeatOption;

  String? _titleError;
  String? _descriptionError;
  String? _dateError;
  String? _timeError;

  final List<String> _repeatOptions = [
    'None',
    'Every 5 seconds',
    'Every 5 minutes',
    'Every 10 minutes',
    'Every 30 minutes',
    'Every day',
    'Every week',
    'Every month'
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedRepeatOption = _repeatOptions[0];
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _titleController.dispose();
    _descriptionController.dispose();
    _dateController.dispose();
    _timeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool isPastDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.isBefore(DateTime.now());
  }

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: now,
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.orange, // Orange color for date picker header
              onPrimary: Colors.white, // White text color on the header
              onSurface: Colors.black, // Black color for the body text
            ),
            dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white, // Background color
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
    if (pickedDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
        _dateController.text = DateFormat('d MMMM yyyy').format(pickedDate);
        _dateError = null;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay? pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.orange, // Orange color for time picker header
              onPrimary: Colors.white, // White text color on the header
              onSurface: Colors.black, // Black color for the body text
            ),
            dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white, // Background color
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
    if (pickedTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedTime = pickedTime;
        _timeController.text = pickedTime.format(context);
        _timeError = null;
      });
    }
  }

  void _validateAndSaveReminder() {
    setState(() {
      _titleError =
          _titleController.text.isEmpty ? 'Please enter a title' : null;
      _descriptionError = _descriptionController.text.isEmpty
          ? 'Please enter a description'
          : null;
      _dateError = _dateController.text.isEmpty ? 'Please select a date' : null;
      _timeError = _timeController.text.isEmpty ? 'Please select a time' : null;
    });

    if (_titleError == null &&
        _descriptionError == null &&
        _dateError == null &&
        _timeError == null) {
      _saveReminder();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _saveReminder() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      final selectedDate = _selectedDate;
      final selectedTime = _selectedTime;

      if (selectedDate == null || selectedTime == null) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Please select a valid date and time')),
        );
        return;
      }

      final dateTime = DateTime(
        selectedDate.year,
        selectedDate.month,
        selectedDate.day,
        selectedTime.hour,
        selectedTime.minute,
      );

      if (isPastDateTime(dateTime)) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('The date and time cannot be in the past.')),
        );
        return;
      }

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      List<String> reminders = prefs.getStringList('reminders') ?? [];

      Map<String, String> newReminder = {
        'title': _titleController.text,
        'description': _descriptionController.text,
        'date': _dateController.text,
        'time': _timeController.text,
        'repeat': _selectedRepeatOption!,
      };

      reminders.add(jsonEncode(newReminder));
      await prefs.setStringList('reminders', reminders);

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Reminder saved successfully!'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        ),
      );

      widget.onReminderSaved();
      Navigator.pop(context, true);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create Reminder', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: _titleController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Title',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  errorText: _titleError,
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _titleError = null;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _descriptionController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Description',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  errorText: _descriptionError,
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _descriptionError = null;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
                child: AbsorbPointer(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _dateController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Date',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      suffixIcon:
                          Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.orange),
                      errorText: _dateError,
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _selectTime(context),
                child: AbsorbPointer(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _timeController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Time',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.access_time, color: Colors.orange),
                      errorText: _timeError,
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: _selectedRepeatOption,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Repeat',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),
                  ),
                ),
                items: _repeatOptions.map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedRepeatOption = newValue;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _validateAndSaveReminder,
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  iconColor: Colors.orange, // Orange background
                  shadowColor: Colors.white, // White text color
                ),
                child: Text('Save Reminder'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
>>>and this si my method to call showNotification form local notification class>>>`static void processExpiredReminders(List<Map<String, String>> reminders,
      List<Map<String, String>> expiredReminders) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(
        seconds: DateTime.now().second,
        microseconds: DateTime.now().microsecond));

    List<Map<String, String>> newExpiredReminders = [];

    reminders.removeWhere((reminder) {
      DateTime? reminderDateTime =
          parseDateTime(reminder['date']!, reminder['time']!);

      if (reminderDateTime != null && reminderDateTime.isBefore(now)) {
        newExpiredReminders.add(reminder);
        print('Reminder expired: $reminder');

        String title = reminder['title'] ?? 'Reminder Expired';
        String description = reminder['description'] ?? 'No Description';
        String notificationBody = description;
        String repeatOption = reminder['repeat'] ?? 'None';

        String payload = json.encode(reminder);

        int notificationId = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;

        try {
          LocalNotifications.showNotification(
            id: notificationId,
            title: title,
            body: notificationBody,
            payload: payload,
            repeatOption: repeatOption,
          );
        } catch (error) {
          print('Error showing notification: $error');
        }

        return repeatOption == 'None';
      }

      return false;
    });

    expiredReminders.addAll(newExpiredReminders);

    if (newExpiredReminders.isNotEmpty) {
      print('Expired reminders added: $newExpiredReminders');
    }
  }

